# Sharepoint site documents webhook subscription using microsoft graph api

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications, webhooks, graph-api, subscriptions

I am trying to get webhook notification from sharepoint sites by using graph api as instructed in [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) document.

From [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type) I confirmed that driveItem can also be used for webhook notification. I created a webapplication which can receive notification and then created another console application which can use graph api to create subscription.

I was able to create a successfull subscription, but on doing on any CRUD operation on any sharepoint site i was not able to get any hits/notification in site notification in my webApplication, is there  any step i am missing or there is issue with Resource parameter in the below shown request body.

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "updated",
    NotificationUrl = "https://176fb499.ngrok.io/SPWebhooksReceiver/api/spwebhook/handlerequest"
    Resource = "/drive/root",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(25),
    ClientState = "A0A354EC-97D4-4D83-9DDB-144077ADB449"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [driveItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) means the content in the hierarchy of a root folder driveItem in OneDrive for Business, or of a root folder or subfolder driveItem in a user's personal OneDrive.

[image: - List item]

You can set the resource on drive item like below:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image]

As the subscribed resource is limited to OneDrive, you may need to perform CRUD operations on OneDrive site to trigger the notifications.

BR